# Addition table to modal and catching data from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I get a problem when I try generate table in modal with data from js code.
There is a problem with 249 line in js. I can not understand why my **params.progress** array is not defined.

[rock-paper-scissors app on codepen](https://codepen.io/traxan/pen/xQMYVp?editors=1010)

I create new object in empty params.progress array after every player move:

```
var objectResults = {
number: params.numberOfRounds,
playerMove: userChoice,
computerMove: computerChoice,
gameResult: params.userScore+":"+params.computerScore,
}
params.progress[params.numberOfRounds] = objectResults;
```

Finally I try to generate table with those data:

```
function makeTableFromProgress() {
 var resultsTableBody = document.querySelector('#resultsTableBody');
 var rows = params.progress.length;
 for (i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
  var row = resultsTableBody.insertRow(i);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
 cell1.innerHTML = params.progress[i]['number'];
 cell2.innerHTML = params.progress[i]['playerMove'];
 cell3.innerHTML = params.progress[i]['computerMove'];
 cell4.innerHTML = params.progress[i]['gameResult'];
 }
}
```

In modal window, like this:

```
  <table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>No.</th>
       <th>Player move</th>
       <th>Computer move</th>
       <th>Game result</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody id="resultsTableBody"></tbody>
   </table>
```

And it brings kind of that problem:

> Cannot read property 'number' of undefined

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? usually, it happens when the list or an object is undefined  like `params.progress[10000]` which is not available!

Comment: Thanks for answer. Number: 1; playerMove: 'Paper'; computerMove: 'Rock'; gameResult: 1:0

Comment: I also wonder why if I have for example 5 rounds of game, its generate array with length(6) not 5. Is there one empty object?

Comment: Darek Adamczyk problem fixed?

Comment: The first item is sometimes *`undefined`*, as I dont know how to play this game so unable to test all cases!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in function `makeTableFromProgress`. `i` must start with **1** instead of **0** and also `insertRow(i - 1);` instead of `insertRow(i);`

```
function makeTableFromProgress() {
  var resultsTableBody = document.querySelector('#resultsTableBody');
  var rows = params.progress.length;
  for (i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
    var row = resultsTableBody.insertRow(i - 1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell1.innerHTML = params.progress[i]['number'];
    cell2.innerHTML = params.progress[i]['playerMove'];
    cell3.innerHTML = params.progress[i]['computerMove'];
    cell4.innerHTML = params.progress[i]['gameResult'];
  }
};
```

The final code will be this

```js
var userScore_span = document.getElementById("user-score");
var computerScore_span = document.getElementById("computer-score");
var scoreBoard_div = document.querySelector(".score-board");
var result_p = document.querySelector(".result > p");
var moveButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-move]");
var newGame_div = document.querySelector(".newGame");
var choices_div = document.querySelector(".choices");
var message_p = document.getElementById("message");
var trophy_p = document.getElementById("numberOfWins");
var roundsCounter_p = document.getElementById("numberOfRounds");
var modal_h = document.getElementById("endMessage");
var userName_div = document.getElementById("user-label");
var userName;
var numberOfGames;
var params = {
  userScore: 0,
  computerScore: 0,
  numberOfRounds: 0,
  progress: []
}


function main() {
  moveButtons.forEach(function(button) {
    var userChoice = button.dataset.move;

    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      game(userChoice);
    });
  });
}

function game(userChoice) {

  var computerChoice = getComputerChoice();

  switch (userChoice + computerChoice) {
    case "RockRock":
    case "PaperPaper":
    case "ScissorsScissors":
      draw(userChoice, computerChoice);
      break;
    case "RockScissors":
    case "PaperRock":
    case "ScissorsPaper":
      win(userChoice, computerChoice);
      break;
    case "RockPaper":
    case "PaperScissors":
    case "ScissorsRock":
      lose(userChoice, computerChoice);
      break;
  }
}

function getComputerChoice() {
  var choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
  return choices[randomNumber];
}

function draw(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  params.numberOfRounds++;
  roundsCounter_p.innerHTML = "Number of rounds: " + params.numberOfRounds;
  computerScore_span.innerHTML = params.computerScore;
  userScore_span.innerHTML = params.userScore;
  var smallerUserWord = "user ".fontsize(4);
  var smallerCompWord = " comp".fontsize(4);
  result_p.innerHTML = smallerUserWord + userChoice + " vs " + computerChoice + smallerCompWord + "<br>It is a draw!";
  document.getElementById(userChoice).classList.add('gray-glow');
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById(userChoice).classList.remove('gray-glow')
  }, 400);
  var objectResults = {
    number: params.numberOfRounds,
    playerMove: userChoice,
    computerMove: computerChoice,
    gameResult: params.userScore + ":" + params.computerScore,
  }
  params.progress[params.numberOfRounds] = objectResults;
}

function win(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  params.numberOfRounds++;
  roundsCounter_p.innerHTML = "Number of rounds: " + params.numberOfRounds;
  params.userScore++;
  userScore_span.innerHTML = params.userScore;
  computerScore_span.innerHTML = params.computerScore;
  var smallerUserWord = "user ".fontsize(4);
  var smallerCompWord = " comp".fontsize(4);
  result_p.innerHTML = smallerUserWord + userChoice + " vs " + computerChoice + smallerCompWord + "<br>You won!";
  document.getElementById(userChoice).classList.add('green-glow');
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById(userChoice).classList.remove('green-glow')
  }, 400);
  var objectResults = {
    number: params.numberOfRounds,
    playerMove: userChoice,
    computerMove: computerChoice,
    gameResult: params.userScore + ":" + params.computerScore,
  }
  params.progress[params.numberOfRounds] = objectResults;
  endGame();
}

function lose(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  params.numberOfRounds++;
  roundsCounter_p.innerHTML = "Number of rounds: " + params.numberOfRounds;
  params.computerScore++;
  computerScore_span.innerHTML = params.computerScore;
  userScore_span.innerHTML = params.userScore;
  var smallerUserWord = "user ".fontsize(4);
  var smallerCompWord = " comp".fontsize(4);
  result_p.innerHTML = smallerUserWord + userChoice + " vs " + computerChoice + smallerCompWord + "<br>You lost!";
  document.getElementById(userChoice).classList.add('red-glow');
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById(userChoice).classList.remove('red-glow')
  }, 400);
  var objectResults = {
    number: params.numberOfRounds,
    playerMove: userChoice,
    computerMove: computerChoice,
    gameResult: params.userScore + ":" + params.computerScore,
  }
  params.progress[params.numberOfRounds] = objectResults;
  endGame();
}

function newGame() {
  newGame_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    howManyWins();
  })
  main();
}

function howManyWins() {
  var userAnswer = prompt("TILL HOW MANY WINS?");
  if (userAnswer === null || userAnswer === "" || isNaN(userAnswer)) {
    thereIsAnError();
  } else {
    giveMeYourName();
    resetScore();
    games(userAnswer);
  }
}

function thereIsAnError() {
  message_p.innerHTML = "Please press NEW GAME and choose the number!";
  setTimeout(function() {
    message_p.innerHTML = ""
  }, 3000);
}


function giveMeYourName() {
  var name = prompt("WHAT IS YOUR NAME?");
  if (name === null || name === "" || isNaN(name) === false) {
    thereIsAnError();
    document.querySelector('#trophy').classList.add('trophydisabled');
  } else if (name.length > 9) {
    message_p.innerHTML = "Your name is too long. 9 letters summary!";
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#trophy').classList.remove('trophydisabled');
    choices_div.classList.remove('choices-disabled');
    newGame_div.classList.add('newGame-disabled');
    userName_div.innerHTML = name;
    userName = name;
  }
}

function resetScore() {
  params.userScore = 0;
  params.computerScore = 0;
  params.numberOfRounds = 0;
  userScore_span.innerHTML = params.userScore;
  computerScore_span.innerHTML = params.computerScore;
  roundsCounter_p.innerHTML = "";
}

function games(userAnswer) {
  trophy_p.innerHTML = "Up to: " + userAnswer;
  numberOfGames = userAnswer;
}


function endGame() {
  if (numberOfGames == params.userScore) {
    choices_div.classList.add('choices-disabled');
    newGame_div.classList.remove('newGame-disabled');
    result_p.innerHTML = "";
    userName_h = userName;
    modal_h.innerHTML = userName + "<br>You won the ENTIRE game!";
    makeTableFromProgress()
    showModal();
  } else if (numberOfGames == params.computerScore) {
    choices_div.classList.add('choices-disabled');
    newGame_div.classList.remove('newGame-disabled');
    showModal();
    result_p.innerHTML = "";
    userName_h = userName;
    modal_h.innerHTML = userName + "<br>You lose the ENTIRE game!";
    makeTableFromProgress()
    showModal();
  }
}

newGame();
choices_div.classList.add('choices-disabled');


//MODAL


var modal = document.getElementById("modal-one");

var showModal = function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector('#modal-overlay').classList.add('show');
  modal.classList.add('show');
};

var hideModal = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector('#modal-overlay').classList.remove('show');
  this.parentElement.classList.remove('show');
};

var closeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.close');

for (var i = 0; i < closeButtons.length; i++) {
  closeButtons[i].addEventListener('click', hideModal);
}

document.querySelector('#modal-overlay').addEventListener('click', hideModal);

var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

for (var i = 0; i < modals.length; i++) {
  modals[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
}

function makeTableFromProgress() {
  var resultsTableBody = document.querySelector('#resultsTableBody');
  var rows = params.progress.length;
  for (i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
    var row = resultsTableBody.insertRow(i - 1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell1.innerHTML = params.progress[i]['number'];
    cell2.innerHTML = params.progress[i]['playerMove'];
    cell3.innerHTML = params.progress[i]['computerMove'];
    cell4.innerHTML = params.progress[i]['gameResult'];
  }
};
```

```css
$black: #000;
$white: #fff;
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #2d3030;
}

header {
  background-color: $white;
  padding: 20px;
}

header>h1 {
  color: #2d3030;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#trophy {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: $white;
  &.trophydisabled {
    display: none;
  }
}

#trophy>p {
  color: $white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.roundsCounter {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.roundsCounter>p {
  color: $white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.score-board {
  margin: 30px auto;
  border: 3px solid $white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  color: $white;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.badge {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #af0e0e;
  color: $white;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

#user-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: -110px;
}

#computer-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: -110px;
}

.result {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: $white;
}

.result>p {
  text-align: center;
}

.newGame {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 250px;
  border: 4px solid $white;
}

.newGame>p {
  padding: 10px;
  color: $white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.newGame:hover p {
  background-color: $white;
  color: #d01115;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#message {
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: $white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.choices {
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.choices button {
  background-color: #2d3030;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 115px;
  border: 4px solid $white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: $white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.choices button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #2d3030;
  ;
  background-color: $white;
}

.challenge {
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: $white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.gray-glow {
  border: 4px solid #787c77;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 10px #787c77;
}

.green-glow {
  border: 4px solid #31b43a;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 10px #31b43a;
}

.red-glow {
  border: 4px solid #d01115;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 10px #d01115;
}

.choices-disabled {
  display: none;
}

.newGame-disabled {
  display: none;
}

.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  &.show {
    display: block;
  }
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  background: $white;
  width: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  &.show {
    display: block;
  }
  .close {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: $black;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  table {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  table th {
    padding: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Rock Paper Scissors Final</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900|Open+Sans:400,700,800&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Rock! Paper! Scissors!</h1>
  </header>

  <div id="trophy">
    <i class="fas fa-trophy"></i>
    <p id="numberOfWins"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="roundsCounter">
    <p id="numberOfRounds"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="score-board">
    <div id="user-label" class="badge">user</div>
    <div id="computer-label" class="badge">comp</div>
    <span id="user-score">0</span>:<span id="computer-score">0</span>
  </div>

  <div class="result">
    <p>Rock beats Scissors
      <br>Paper covers Rock
      <br>Scissors cuts Paper</p>
  </div>

  <div class="newGame">
    <p>New Game</p>
  </div>

  <p id="message"></p>

  <div class="choices">
    <button class="player-move" id="Rock" data-move="Rock">
                <i class="fas fa-hand-rock"></i>
            </button>
    <button class="player-move" id="Paper" data-move="Paper">
                <i class="fas fa-hand-paper"></i>
            </button>
    <button class="player-move" id="Scissors" data-move="Scissors">
                <i class="fas fa-hand-scissors"></i>
            </button>
  </div>
  <p class="challenge">Let me defeat you!</p>

  <div class="overlay" id="modal-overlay">
    <div class="modal" id="modal-one">
      <a href="#" class="close"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
      <h2 id="endMessage">""</h2>
      <h3><br>How it was?</h3>

      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Player move</th>
            <th>Computer move</th>
            <th>Game result</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="resultsTableBody"></tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```